# SignalR no actualiza ng-view al cambiar de pagina

Tags: javascript, angularjs, signalr

1.- Es un simple ng-route, tengo 3 botones, cada boton navega a una nueva ruta.

2.- Tengo un controller padre y uno hijo para el `ng-view`

3.- Para el `ng-view` tengo una plantilla con un span ligado a la propiedad `subCtrl.id` y otro span ligado a `'subCtrl.something'` con un valor inicial de `something.id=1` and `something.name='blondie'`

4.-Si llamo el metodo signalR a travez de Fiddler y estoy  en **la ruta inicial** todo funciona bien: SignalR actualiza la vista con 'Angel Eyes'

**PROBLEMA**: PERO si cambio la ruta y navego a ctrl.optionSelected(2) o ctrl.optionSelected(3) y llamo el metodo SignalR a travez de FIDDLER, el cliente lo recibe y la consola imprime 'Angel eyes', Sin embargo la vista no se actualiza!

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl as ctrl">
    <button ng-click="ctrl.optionSelected(1)">1</button>
    <button ng-click="ctrl.optionSelected(2)">2</button>
    <button ng-click="ctrl.optionSelected(3)">3</button>
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/app.js"></script>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/:id', {
        templateUrl: '/Templates/template.html',
        controller: 'subCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'sctrl'
    });
}]);

app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$location', function ($location) {
   var self = this;
   self.optionSelected = function (option) {
      $location.path("/" + option);
   };

}]);

app.controller('subCtrl', ['$routeParams', '$scope', function ($routeParams, $scope) {
    var self = this;
    self.something= {};
    self.something.id = $routeParams.id;
    self.something.name = 'Blondie';

    self.hub = $.connection.AppHub;

    /*****HERE IS THE PROBLEM*************/
    self.hub.client.Hello = function () {
         console.log("Angel eyes");
         self.something.name= 'Angel eyes';
         $scope.$apply();
         };
    /*************************************/
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    console.log('SignalR connection started');
    });
}]);
```

Templates/Template.html

```
<span ng-bind="sctrl.something.id"></span>
<span ng-bind="sctrl.something.name"></span>
```

SIGNAL R metodo:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/app/GetSignalRTest")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetSignalRTest()
    {
     var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<AppHub>();
     context.Clients.All.hello();  
     return Ok();
    }
```

El codigo y la explicacion estan largos, pero en realidad es muy simple, favor de ver los siguientes GIFS:

Funciona con la ruta inicial:

[image]

No funciona despues de cambiar la ruta:

[image]

Que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que veo sucede es que el attach al evento del `SignalR` lo esta recibiendo el primer controller por eso el segundo no toma la accion.

Podrias mover la definicion de SignalR al controller base quien se encargue de recibir toda la comunicacion y este la envie mediente evento a los controller hijo

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$location', function ($location) {
   var self = this;
   self.optionSelected = function (option) {
      $location.path("/" + option);
   };

    self.hub = $.connection.AppHub;


    self.hub.client.Hello = function () {
         console.log("Hello");
         $scope.$broadcast('UpdateName', 'Angel eyes');
         };

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        console.log('SignalR connection started');
    });

}]);

app.controller('subCtrl', ['$routeParams', '$scope', function ($routeParams, $scope) {
    var self = this;
    self.something= {};
    self.something.id = $routeParams.id;
    self.something.name = 'Blondie';

    $scope.$on('UpdateName', function(name) 
    { 
        self.something.name = name;
        $scope.$apply();
    });

}]);
```

como veras uso el `$broadcast` y `$on` para comunicar los controller

[Understanding $emit, $broadcast and $on in AngularJS](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/angularjs/HM0L291214-Understanding-$emit,-$broadcast-and-$on-in-AngularJS.html)

Comment: Justamente se me acaba de ocurrir esto, pero no sabia usar el $emit o el $broadcast y estaba investigando +1 voy a verificar

Comment: No llega a $scope.on en el subcontroller

Comment: actualice el codigo, cambia el $emit por el $broadcast

Answer (score 0):

Gracias Leandro, basicamente es tu respuesta con unos ajustes:

En el mainCtrl use $rootScope en vez de $scope y $broadcast en vez de $emit:

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$location', '$scope', '$rootScope', function ($location, $scope, $rootScope) {

var self = this;
self.optionSelected = function (option) {
    $location.path("/" + option);
}
self.hub = $.connection.AppHub;


self.hub.client.Hello = function () {
    console.log("Hello");
    $rootScope.$broadcast('UpdateName', 'Angel eyes');
};

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    console.log('SignalR connection started');
    });
}]);
```

En el cliente recibo el nombre del metodo y el valor, y actualizo la vista:

```
$scope.$on('UpdateName', function (name,value) {
    self.something.name = value;
    $rootScope.$apply();
});
```